# Bottom aligning div without specifying parent container height

Tags: css

I have some html like this

```
<div class="gRow">
    <div class="cell c9 right last">Text</div>
    <div class="cell c8 right gCol8">Long text wrapped over multiple lines</div>
    <div class="cell c7 right gCol7">Text</div>
</div>
```

See this fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/LmZYE/

What I would like is to have the two "Text" div's align to the bottom of the gRow div.

I don't know the height of gRow at render time as the text changes with selected language. I have tried positioning gRow relative and my inner div's absolute, bottom:0 but in vain.

Can I do what I'm trying to do or do I need to know the height of the gRow div?

[image]

EDIT: Forgot one thing: I would like to have a right border going all the way from the top to the bottom of gRow.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is a rework of the HTML allowed?

Comment: what are you wanting the end thing to look like? can you change the order of your html?

Comment: @limelights: Rework is allowed as I control the html.

Comment: @Pete: The row is for a grid where the left most column is left floated and text-align left. The rest of the columns are floated right and text-align right.

Comment: What is the center div supposed to do if the two text boxes behave how you want?  Could you provide a mockup of what you want the final product to look like?

Comment: something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/LmZYE/2/

Comment: why not use a table - this look like tabular data

Comment: @Pete: Yes! Definitely something like that! I have added a screenshot to illustrate work in progress. It'll probably give you a better idea.

Comment: I prefer to do this without tables. I have to be able to expand rows and inject non grid data using ajax.

Comment: The display `table`, `table-row` and `table-cell` would help you. But they don't work if any of divs are floated. So you can't have the first div floated right. http://jsfiddle.net/mx9E2/2/ If that works for you (and you can drop the floating stuff), let me know and I'll post as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to do this using divs rather than a table you can use the css for `display:table` to make your divs respond like a table would:

**html**

```
<div class="table">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="cell c9 right last">Text</div>
        <div class="cell c8 right gCol8">Long text wrapped over multiple lines</div>
        <div class="cell c7 right gCol7">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**css**

```
.table {display:table; border-right: 1px solid red;}
.row {display:table-row;}
.cell {border-left: 1px solid red; display:table-cell; width:33%;}
```

Then you can keep adding rows and cells as you please.

You are also able to take advantage of the `vertical-align` property for if you want to align text to the middle or bottom of the div

http://jsfiddle.net/LmZYE/6/

Comment: Thanks @Pete. For some reason I just can't get vertical-align: bottom to respond. My gRow is display: table and all my cells are display-type: table-cell. Any ideas as to what might be the disturbing factor?

Comment: it should be `display:table-cell` rather than `display-type`

Comment: Well... I'm using Chrome for development but it has to be able to run in The Evil Browser (IE8). I think I still have some floats disturbing the layout.

Comment: !!! I wan't to have your baby! It looks good now. The order is wrong as I have processed the columns in reverse order due to the float right. I'll fix that and I think I'm good to go. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood the question right, [this](http://jsfiddle.net/LmZYE/3/) is what you're looking for.

HTML

```
<div class="gRow">
    <div class="cell c8 right gCol8">Long text wrapped over multiple lines</div>
    <div class="bottomRow">
        <div class="cell c9 right last">Text</div>
        <div class="cell c7 right gCol7">Text</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.gRow {
    width:400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #d3d3d3;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
.bottomRow {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.c7, .c8, .c9 {
    width:80px
}
.right {
    float: right;
}
.cell {
    border-left: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: Nope - the border does not go all the way through from top to bottom. Pete is more on the money with his suggestion (though I can't get it to work - but I will) :-)